# Determining why Redis is receiving a SIGTERM every minute or two

Tags: ubuntu, redis, ubuntu-16.04

I'm running redis-server on Ubuntu 16.04.  After a recent upgrade to redis 3.2.7 I now see lines like

`signal-handler (1486427812) Received SIGTERM scheduling shutdown...`

every minute or two in the redis log and then redis restarts.

The only other suspicious line in the logs is:

`# WARNING: The TCP backlog setting of 511 cannot be enforced because /proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn is set to the lower value of 128.`

Any advice on how to diagnose why this is happening would be greatly appreciated.   Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just for the record:
As in J G Miller's comment, you have to watch that "Type=simple" and "daemonize yes" settings are incompatible. I struggeld a few days while I found this comment. My redis just simply gave the start-limit-hit error because when the service started it immediately got the SIGTERM signal and stopped.

So either change in the service file the "Type=forking" or the "daemonize no" lines to solve this, depending on your needs.

Comment: Also make sure the location of the PID file from the redis config matches the one specified in the systemd unit file (had this issue when running in sentinel mode).

Comment: this worked on ubuntu 22.04 after upgrading from 20.04

Answer (score 13):

For anyone else still looking for a solution, `Type=forking` (which is default for redis installed with `apt`) is incompatible with `supervised=systemd` in `redis.conf`.

It has to be updated to `Type=simple` in `/etc/systemd/system/redis.service`.

Forking is only required in daemonized mode, but systemd managed redis overrules the daemonized setting.

Change from `Restart=always` to `Restart=on-failure`

For reference- redis.conf, https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In case you weren't aware, you can edit your posts after they've been posted by clicking the "Edit" link towards the bottom of the post.

Answer (score 4):

This was solved by an apt-get purge and re-install. The old init file wasn't playing nicely with the redis.conf file.

Comment: For anybody else having a problem with redis-server not starting up with systemd unit service file, if "Type=simple" (the default so entry not necessarily present), in redis.conf ensure that "daemonize" is set to  "no", otherwise redis fails to start with the perplexing message user requested shutdown/received SIGTERM.

Comment: Was struggling from a couple of days on the very same issue!! Thank you, bless SO ! :)